# laravel ftp works on windows but not in linux

Tags: linux, laravel, ftp, vsftpd

```
#config\filesystems.php
'ftp' => [
    'driver' => 'ftp',
    'host' => '52.221.127.xx',
    'username' => 'xxx',
    'password' => 'password',
    'passive' => false,
    'timeout' => 100,
],


#vsftpd config 

listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
local_umask=022
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=NO
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list

allow_writeable_chroot=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

port_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
data_connection_timeout=100

pasv_promiscuous=YES
utf8_filesystem=YES
```

my laravel code:

```
$document = $request->file('document');
$attributes['courseware_data'] = $document->storeAs($save_path, $save_name, 'ftp');
```

I have run command `:chmod 777 -R /var/ftp` on the linux server.

It works in my windows computer ,but when I push the code to the `production` environment, I receive the following error:

> ftp_fput(): Illegal PORT command.

I turn the passive `true` and `false`, it always turn out this error.

Thank you stranger.

Comment: i guess this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526034/ftp-get-illegal-port-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ftp\_get: Illegal PORT command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526034/ftp-get-illegal-port-command)